# 64-bit JDK configuration in Eclipse JUNO

Tags: java, eclipse

What is it missing in my `eclipse.ini`. I tried reference from [wiki.eclipse.org](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

My environment is

- 64-bit Window 7
- 64-bit JDK (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe)
- eclipse version=4.2.0

`Eclipse JUNO`

Error

```
Java was started but returned exit code=13
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-jar D:\java\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash D:\java\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
-launcher D:\java\eclipse\eclipse.exe
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library D:\java\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup D:\java\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 139c_80
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-jar D:\java\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
```

eclipse.ini

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 
512m
--launcher.defaultAction 
openFile
-product 
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction 
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize 
512M
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: Looks like you're running a 32-bit eclipse

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb yes? I am sure, I download 64-bit IDE. Base on error, look like 32-bit IDE?

Comment: Check launcher.library plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86

Comment: The 64-bit version of eclipse has the follow plugin: plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835. Notice the x86_64 missing. Did you copy a eclipse.ini from a  32-bit version eclipse?

Comment: I download and install `launchers-win32.win32.x86_64.3.8.1.zip` which `org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120522-1813`. It is not ok, also.

Answer (score 2):

You have 32 bit Juno and 64 bit jdk it is the problem

Comment: Nope, I have 64-bit IDE, but `launcher.library` config is missing, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you need all the components in 64 bit version.

- Eclipse
- JDK
- Platform

Comment: No, you only need matching 32 or 64 bit versions of Eclipse and JRE/JDK. The platform can be 64 bit and Eclipse + JDK can be 32 bit. Ref: http://superuser.com/questions/246863/running-32bit-eclipse-on-64bit-windows

Comment: @Fredrik : I believe he was trying to run a 64 bit version of Eclipse, so for that he will need all the 3 things matching to 64 bit.

Comment: No, that not correct. He could use 64 bit Windows + 32 bit Eclipse + 32 bit JDK and that would work. Or 64 bit windows + 64 bit Eclipse + 64 bit JDK. JDK and Eclipse have to match. Ideal is to use 64 bit for all, but it is not required.

Comment: @Fredrik I dont want to get into a arguing match but dont you see from the CycDemo comments that he wish to run 64 bit Eclipse and for "64 bit Eclipse" he needs all three in 64 bit.